# Publish ClickOnce installation error "Exception reading from manifest" using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, vb.net-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). My target environment is [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) Framework 4.0.

So I'm facing this problem when I'm publishing my project by using the provided `Setup.exe` file. After the verifying application requirement popped up, an alert popped up with text:

> Cannot Continue. The application is improperly formatted. Contact the application vendor for assistance.

When I clicked on the "Detail" button, it showed me this error:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows                 : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime : 4.0.30319.239
System.Deployment.dll   : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
clr.dll                 : 4.0.30319.239 (RTMGDR.030319-2300)
dfdll.dll               : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
dfshim.dll              : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
Deployment URL          : file:///I:/ProjectBMTRelease/ProjectBMT.application

IDENTITIES
Deployment Identity     : ProjectBMT.application, Version=1.0.0.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7439f62500c0364d, processorArchitecture=x86

APPLICATION SUMMARY
* Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of I:\ProjectBMTRelease\ProjectBMT.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Exception reading manifest from file:///I:/ProjectBMTRelease/Application%20Files/ProjectBMT_1_0_0_6/ProjectBMT.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
    + Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed:
        -HRESULT:       0x80070c81
         Start line:    0
         Start column:  0
         Host file:
    + Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070C81

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [6/23/2012 5:21:36 PM] : Activation of I:\ProjectBMTRelease\ProjectBMT.application has started.
* [6/23/2012 5:21:36 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
* [6/23/2012 5:21:36 PM] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [6/23/2012 5:21:36 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
    - Exception reading manifest from file:///I:/ProjectBMTRelease/Application%20Files/ProjectBMT_1_0_0_6/ProjectBMT.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
    - Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed:
        -HRESULT:       0x80070c81
         Start line:    0
         Start column:  0
         Host file:
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)
        at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest..ctor(FileStream fileStream)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
    - Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070C81
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateCMSFromXml(Byte[] buffer, UInt32 bufferSize, IManifestParseErrorCallback Callback, Guid& riid)
        at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

I checked my project's manifest file, but I am not good enough to find any problem there. For other information, I created simple "Hello World !" application to see if it will get published well, and it did.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following:

- Does the user have .NET 4 installed on their computer?
- How are you publishing the application, are you using Visual Studio?
- Are you making any changes to the deployment after publishing it?
- If you are manually moving the files to the deployment location, is the structure identical to the original structure?

Try enabling detailed logging and see if that provides more information.

Comment: I'm not seeing any enhanced logs here on a .Net 4 client PC installing a .Net 4 app. I am trying to diagnose a 'the application is improperly formatted' error, so perhaps the logging only kicks in once the manifests have been validated and the installation starts for real(?)

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the path for the log files to a path the user can write to? Be sure to put it in mydocuments or something like that, not in c:\somefolder.

Comment: Actually that log file is opened for you when you click the button to provide more info when a problem occurs at installation time. I didn't realise that that info was the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I got this very same error. The problem got resolved after I renamed my assembly name found on the first tab under application properties. It seems like having an assembly name with a space creates a manifest filename with a blank space and it seems to create problems. My application assembly name was named "Capital Manager". After I changed it to "Capital_Manager" (I replaced the space with an under score "_") the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I received an error report and call stack pretty much identical to yours when attempting to run the ClickOnce installer. My findings so far may be helpful to others arriving here, so I'll post the details, but I have a feeling this same error report may be caused by a range of different problems.

The first thing I noticed was that my application manifest (the one that lists all of the files for the application + a signature hash for each) had entries for assemblies that had an invalid publicKeyToken, for example,

```
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1">
  <asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="foo.exe" version="1.2.3.4" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" type="win32" />
```

Further down the file instead of seeing **dependentAssembly** elements for assemblies some of the assemblies were listed as plain content files (**file** elements).

These problems certainly make the ClickOnce deployment invalid, and the cause was using a version of [Mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that was compiled against an older version of [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) than the assemblies it was trying to create manifests for. When creating the application manifest Mage will attempt to read assemblies as follows:

```
AssemblyIdentity.FromFile(fileName);
```

And for Mage compiled against .NET 3.5 ([CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) 2.0) trying to load a .NET 4.0 assembly results in a [BadImageFormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) exception which is handled, and the fall-back behaviour is to treat these files as content files.

Answer (score 1):

Does your application folder have subfolders? I got this same HRESULT just yesterday, and the root cause was that a library (EntityFramework.dll) was in both the top level and in a subfolder. (There was a MAGE warning about this, but it was not handled as an error.) I updated my script to remove EntityFramework.dll from the subfolder, and the ClickOnce is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Just another possibility - I got a similar error when adding a dpiAware to a newly created app.manifest file. ClickOnce started failing immediately.

I followed the advise here: [Installing ClickOnce published DPI-aware application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864672/installing-clickonce-published-dpi-aware-application)

So if you've been doing dpi things, maybe look there.